# Directory listing fails in FileZilla

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I am trying to connect to a FTP server with Filezilla. It was working when I was using broadband but when I use my college internet it says:

```
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I tried both passive and active mode but all in vain. It connects but fails to give directory listing.

Below is the complete log for active mode

```
Status: Resolving address of where2service.com
Status: Connecting to 166.62.2.1:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 22 of 500 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 05:09. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER where2service
Response:   331 User where2service OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PORT 192,168,126,200,228,90
Response:   200 Port command successful.
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226-Options: -a -l 
Response:   226 18 matches total
Error:  Connection timed out
```

Below is the log for passive mode:

```
Status: Resolving address of where2service.com
Status: Connecting to 166.62.2.1:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220---------- Welcome to Pure-FTPd [privsep] [TLS] ----------
Response:   220-You are user number 20 of 500 allowed.
Response:   220-Local time is now 05:13. Server port: 21.
Response:   220-This is a private system - No anonymous login
Response:   220 You will be disconnected after 3 minutes of inactivity.
Command:    USER where2service
Response:   331 User where2service OK. Password required
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   230 OK. Current restricted directory is /
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is your current location
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (166,62,2,1,174,209)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   150 Accepted data connection
Response:   226-Options: -a -l 
Response:   226 18 matches total
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: In my case, restarting the router which I was using to connect to the Internet worked. I think It was an IP issue in my case.

Answer (score 43):

It working fine after update my Encryption to "**Only use plain FTP (insecure)**"

Comment: I'm using **"Only use plain FTP (insecure)"** but getting the same error.

Comment: This exposes your username and password in unencrypted plain text to anyone listening on the network. They could then use those credentials to log on to your server and download your files, or make changes to your files in place. Only use this solution if the security of the files on your server is unimportant.

Comment: This does not work for me

Answer (score 39):

It's solved, go to **File>Site Manager**, select your Site and in that you have to set, "**Encryption: Only use plain FTP(Insecure)**" and finally connect. 
[As you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLHcI.png)

Answer (score 11):

FTP Connection fails at 'Retrieving Directory Listing' or 'Connection Established, waiting for welcome message'. Please follow the below steps and this may help you.

1. Open Filezilla and open the settings (under the Edit menu)
2. Under "Connection" select "FTP"
3. The section at the top is called Transfer Mode. Within that, choose
   "Passive Mode"
4. Click OK. You should now be able to connect.

Answer (score 6):

In active mode, you send:

```
Command:    PORT 192,168,126,200,228,90
```

This is a private IP address. The server cannot connect to that one. So this definitely does not work for servers on the Internet. If you have to use active mode, you need to open your firewall/router to forward incoming FTP connections to your computer. In FileZilla, open the settings (`Connection` → `FTP` → `Active mode`) and configure them accordingly.

In passive mode, you send:

```
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (166,62,2,1,174,209)
```

This means that the FTP server asked you to connect to that IP and port. If you are firewalled, you cannot connect to it. If the server is not properly set up and firewalled as well, it won't see your incoming connection.

For more information, have a look at the [network configuration article](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration) in the FileZilla wiki.

Comment: Under Site Manager click you FTP site -> Transfer Settings tab select Active mode and then connect. That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Tried all of the above but didn't work. Finally chose to run Filezilla as administrator... problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

When i connect to my hosting ftp server, i got below error.

```
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message... 
Status: Initializing TLS... 
Status: Verifying certificate... 
Status: TLS connection established. 
Status: Logged in 
Status: Retrieving directory listing... 
Command: PWD Response: 257 "/" is your current location 
Command: TYPE I Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary 
Command: PASV 
Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (138,128,162,194,117,133) 
Command: MLSD Error: Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

This is the correct path for solve above question. I am using filezilla as my ftp client application.

1. Click on “File” menu and click on top of the “Site Manager” icon.
2. In encryption section choose “only use plain FTP” from drop down.
3. Also change logon type to "Normal".

[image]